# Can svg image be used as the icon for the React Full Calendar v4 'customButtons'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to display a 'filterIcon' before the text of `customButtons`. Following the docs of React Fullcalendar, it suggests to use 'icon' key to the 'customButtons' object, which I did - but after doing so, only an empty button is displayed in the browser. What would be the best approach to solve this issue?

**SVG image:**

```
import filterLine from 'images/NewIcons/filterlines.svg';
```

**Calendar properties**

```
export const CALENDAR_PROPERTIES = {
    plugins: [interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin],
    header: {
        left: 'prev, title, next',
        right: 'today, dayGridMonth, timeGridWeek, timeGridDay, myCustomButton ',
    },
    views: {},
    weekends: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    editable: true,
    droppable: false,
    columnHeader: true,
    dayMinWidth: true,
    buttonText: {
        today: 'Today',
        month: 'Month',
        week: 'Week',
        day: 'Day',
    },
    nowIndicator: false,
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    eventLimit: true,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: false,
    weekNumbers: true,
};
```

**Function handling the calendar initialization:**

```
handleCalendar(calendarEl) {
   const { tours } = this.props;
   const events = this.getEvents(tours);
   calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        ...CALENDAR_PROPERTIES,
        events,
        eventPositioned: this.handleEventPositioned,
        loading: loadingCalendar => this.setState({ loadingCalendar }),
        select: this.handleDateSelect,
        eventDrop: this.handleEventDrop,
        eventClick: this.handleEventClick,
        customButtons: {
            myCustomButton: {
                text: 'Filter',
                **icon: filterLine,**
                click: () => {
                    this.setState({ isTourItemModalOpen: true });
                },
            },
        },
        columnHeaderFormat: { weekday: 'long' },
    });
}
```

**Button before adding the icon:**
[image: Button before adding the icon]

**Button after adding the icon:**
[image: Button after adding the icon]

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/buttonIcons: _"These icon string are transformed into classNames which are styled by FullCalendar’s CSS"_ ... so I don't believe you can put the URL of the icon directly as the string in the button config.